# How to use sitemap in firebase hosting with react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, sitemap, firebase-hosting, google-search-api

I have deployed a reactjs web app on my firebase hosting. I added a sitemap.xml file to the public folder. I edited `firebase.json` to route the source to sitemap.xml:

```
"redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/sitemap",
        "destination": "/sitemap.xml",
        "type": 302
      }
    ],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/*",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

But when ever I go `https://blah blah.com/sitemap` it always returns `index.html` I tried to add it to rewrites as well but it seems it always returns `index.html`.

I am using `React Router 4` as well for routing, maybe that effects this.

```
<Switch>
        <Route component={Login} exact path="/login" />
        <Route component={Home} path="/home" />
        <Route component={About} path="/about" />
        <Route component={Carousel} path="/carousel/:galleryRef/:ref" />
        <Route component={RelayEditPage} path="/edit/:galleryRef" />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
      </Switch>
```

How can I add the sitemap to hosting domain? If I add a `Redirect` component inside the `Switch` it works but then I am unable to set Google search console sitemap because of the redirect.

Comment: Try removing any reference to `sitemap.xml` from `firebase.json`. Since you have a static file that exists there it should just get returned based on [hosting priorities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)

Comment: @abraham Thank you for your reply. I have removed all references but when I execute `domain.com/sitemap.xml` it always falls back to `/` and loads home page.

Comment: How ever if I run this on localhost it works. Only the firebase hosting is redirecting me to ‘/‘ always

Comment: It's working fine for me in my experiment. [Example](https://nomadic-botany-643.firebaseapp.com/sitemap.xml) and [Source](https://github.com/abraham/firebase-hosting-sitemap).

Comment: @abraham can you provide a snippet of your firebase.json hosting part ?

Comment: The entire source is linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @abraham Thank you. :) I don't understand, I have almost the same setup except I have a React app. It is not working if I put the `sitemap.xml` to the path it renders  only the navbar and footer as those two are outside the `Switch` rendering the pages.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
"redirects": [
  {
    "source": "/sitemap",
    "destination": "/sitemap.xml",
    "type": 301
  },
  {
    "source": "/sitemap/**",
    "destination": "/sitemap.xml",
    "type": 302
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting index.html file.
I have created a website in that I deleted the index.html from public folder and instead used index.js in functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Using the following configuration made the files in my public folder (including the sitemap) accessible online after deployment:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/sitemap",
    "destination": "/sitemap.xml"
  }
]
```